# pregmatch to get text inside a href

Tags: php, preg-match-all

HTML:

```
 <td class="td_class"><a href="javascript:goRead('115');" onmouseover="status='read';return true;" onmouseout="status=''" onfocus="blur()">Title</a></td>
```

I need to make preg_match to get the title, i already try using this regex

```
preg_match_all('/[^>]class=["\']td_class[\'"]*>(.*?)<\//',$result,$match);
    $datas['title'] = $match[1];
    var_dump($datas['title']);
```

and the result is

```
 <a href="javascript:goRead('115');" onmouseover="status='read';return true;" onmouseout="status=''" onfocus="blur()">Title</a>
```

But i want to get only the title, anyone know how to do it?
Thank you!

Comment: You should use a **DOM Parser** like **DomDocument**.It's easy to use for that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DomDocument** works really well,  [doc here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

A quick example

```
  //This steps is useful if you want to parse html of a website
  $html = file_get_contents('www.pathtohtml.com');
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  //if you want to load html file you can use loadHtmlFile
  $doc->loadHTML($html); //This load html string
  $aTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a'); 
  foreach ($aTags as $aTag) {
    //$aTag->nodeValue this contain your A tag text node!
    //You can also access attributes ..
  }
```

If you need to query more precisely the Dom i advice you [XPATH](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

Hope this helps.

Comment: i need to use preg-match this time, do you know how to do it? i tried every regex that i found but still nothing work

Comment: why this is a need?

Comment: it will be used for scraping website, and it need to use preg-match, so we can compare which one is better

Comment: try this `<a (?:.+)>(.+)<\/a>` as a pattern